# gulp zip directories with different bases

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, build-tools, gulp-4

I'm using gulp 4. I have the following file structure:

`├── gulpfile.js
├── dir1
└── src
    ├── dir2`

I want to zip `dir1` and `dir2` together in the same layer, i.e. not including `src` directory.

How can I do it with gulp?

One option I can think of is having to different tasks to copy them to a tmp directory then zip them with the base = tmp. But I want to find a better solution.

Thanks,

Comment: I assume you want to maintain the folder structure, dir1 and dir2, not just get the files in those folders?  Otherwise it is easy.

Comment: yeah, right. I want to maintain the folder structure

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [gulp-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=gulp-rename).  The idea being to rename your directories to leave only the last folder.  This works in your case since your just want "dir1" and "dir2" but could be generalized with some work.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');
const zip = require('gulp-zip');

const path = require('path');
const debug = require('gulp-debug');

gulp.task('zipp', function () {

  return gulp.src(['./dir1/*', 'src/dir2/*'], {base: '.'})

    .pipe(rename(function (file) {

      // is there a "/" or "\" (your path.sep) in the dirname?

      let index = file.dirname.indexOf(path.sep.toString());

      if (index != -1) {

        // if there is a folder separator, keep only that part just beyond it
        // so src/dir2 becomes just dir2
        file.dirname = file.dirname.slice(index+1);
      }
    }))

    // just to see the new names (and folder structure) of all the files
    .pipe(debug({ title: 'src' }))

    .pipe(zip('_final.zip'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
});
```

Note: I originally tried using [gulp-flatten](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-flatten) which seems like a good candidate for this, but I couldn't get it to work.

[**Edit**]: I went back to get it to work with **gulp-flatten** and it is very easy in your case.  Just replace the rename() pipe with

```
const flatten = require('gulp-flatten');

.pipe(flatten({includeParents: -1 }))
```

That will reduce the folder structure to just the last folder in each file's path sequence.